# how to connect to robot and run a node in a new terminal

Tags: python, terminal, ros, gnome

I have lots of terminals that I have to open parallelly in order to run my script (e.g launching the simulator, enabling the robot, opening the GUI, connecting to the camera and more). I know how to open a new gnome-terminal and run multiples commands, but if the first command is "connecting to the robot" I can't continue to the next one.

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/sh -c '/home/erez/ros_ws/baxter.sh ; rosrun project_x gui_project_x'
```

after running the first script (baxter.sh) I can use the new terminal normally and connected to the robot. in order to make the next command run (rosrun project...) i have to press ctrl+D.

Comment: Why do you need many terminals? Write a shell script and execute it in one terminal.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea and i would look into it! the problem right now is that i can't connect to the robot and then run a command in one shell.

Comment: Why can't you continue to the next one?